# A simple way to animate a marker/icon along a linear path from geojson origin to destination in Mapbox js

Tags: javascript, animation, mapbox, geojson

I need to animate a png mapbox marker icon from point-a(origin) to point-b(destination) on a linear path. Using mapbox geojson coords:

```
var start = {lat: 90.40237426757811, lng: 23.75015391301012}
var end = {lat: 88.34930419921875, lng: 22.573438264572406}
```

I have referenced the Mapbox docs, but the [examples](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/) of marker animation along geojson coordinates do not work for small linear distances i.e. less than 200meters. They (the Mapbox examples) also don't show how to control speed.

Have also tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-animation) but it totally swaps out the Mapbox API and is breaking my solution that uses the latest version of Mapbox. Hoping that maybe someone has had to animate markers in geojson coords along a linear path.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the addTo(map) actually moves the marker on the map. I was mistaken in thinking that every time this method is called it removes and re-adds the marker to the map. This is wrong, it moves the marker to the new coordinate.

This means that if you are using this method you can add a css class to the marker/icon and then use css animations to control the speed and movement of the marker between the 2 coordinates.

Comment: Above meaning move from original coordinate to the new coordinate. CSS animation used:


        .car1 {
            z-index: 12;
            animation: pulseone 2s infinite;
        }
                    @-webkit-keyframes pulseone {
          0% {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(70, 149, 177, 0.4);
          }
          70% {
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(70, 149, 177, 0);
          }
          100% {
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(70, 149, 177, 0);
          }
        }